# Identify period intervals between two dates

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g

I have a table called billing_cycle and it has customer wise billing pay period information like monthly, weekly, bi-weekly, Quarterly, Yearly.
Table Columns : Customer , Frequency, billing_start_date

Example:

```
Customer , Frequency, billing_start_date
001 , Monthly , 04-Feb-2021
002 , Weekly ,  01-Mar-2021
003 , Bi-Weekly , 01-Mar-2021
```

My requirement is, I want to identify (query) what are the billing periods based on frequency type for a customer between given date range (From and To)

For example, Given date range is 01-Feb-2021 to 30-Oct-2021.

Then out put for customer 001(Monthly frequency) is

```
Pay_period_start ,  Pay_period_end
01-Feb-2021 , 28-Feb-2021
01-Mar-2021 , 31-Mar-2021
01-Apr-2021 , 30-Apr-2021 and so on till
01-Oct-2021 to 31-Oct-2021
```

Output for customer 002 (weekly interval 7 days):

```
Pay_period_start ,  Pay_period_end
01-Feb-2021 , 07-Feb-2021
08-Feb-2021 , 14-Feb-2021
15-Feb-2021 , 21-Feb-2021
22-Feb-2021 , 28-Feb-2021
01-Mar-2021 , 07-Mar-2021 and so on till
31-Oct-2021
```

and similarly for Customer 003 on Bi-weekly basis(15 days).

Comment: Postgres or Oracle?

Comment: Anything is fine. I need to find out solution for both Oracle and Postgresql

Comment: Why does Customer 002 have to pay in February when their billing starts in March? Shouldn't the first `pay_period_start` for customer `002` be `2021-03-01`?

Answer (score 0):

Get the average time between pay peroids. Create a case statement

case when timediff = 7 then weekly when timediff = 14 then biweekly else monthly end

you can fill in the other values for quarterly yearly and such

Answer (score 0):

Here's Oracle code; see if it helps.

Setting date format (just to see *what is what*; you don't have to do that):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Here we go (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  -- This is your sample table
  3  customer (customer, frequency, billing_start_date) as
  4    (select '001', 'Monthly'  , date '2021-04-02' from dual union all
  5     select '002', 'Weekly'   , date '2021-03-01' from dual union all
  6     select '003', 'Bi-Weekly', date '2021-03-01' from dual
  7    ),
  8  -- Date range, as you stated
  9  date_range (start_date, end_date) as
 10    (select date '2021-02-01', date '2021-10-30' from dual
 11    )
 12  -- Billing periods
 13  select
 14    c.customer,
 15    --
 16    case when c.frequency = 'Monthly'   then add_months(d.start_date, column_value - 1)
 17         when c.frequency = 'Weekly'    then d.start_date + ( 7 * (column_value - 1))
 18         when c.frequency = 'Bi-Weekly' then d.start_date + (14 * (column_value - 1))
 19    end as pay_period_start,
 20    --
 21    case when c.frequency = 'Monthly'   then add_months(d.start_date, column_value - 0) - 1
 22         when c.frequency = 'Weekly'    then d.start_date + ( 7 * (column_value - 0)) - 1
 23         when c.frequency = 'Bi-Weekly' then d.start_date + (14 * (column_value - 0)) - 1
 24    end as pay_period_end
 25  from customer c cross join date_range d
 26                  cross join table(cast(multiset(select level
 27                                                 from dual
 28                                                 connect by level <= case when c.frequency = 'Monthly'   then months_between(d.end_date, d.start_date)
 29                                                                          when c.frequency = 'Weekly'    then (d.end_date - d.start_date) / 7
 30                                                                          when c.frequency = 'Bi-Weekly' then (d.end_date - d.start_date) / 14
 31                                                                     end + 1
 32                                                ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 33  order by c.customer, pay_period_start;
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMER   PAY_PERIOD_START     PAY_PERIOD_END
---------- -------------------- --------------------
001        01.02.2021           28.02.2021
001        01.03.2021           31.03.2021
001        01.04.2021           30.04.2021
001        01.05.2021           31.05.2021
001        01.06.2021           30.06.2021
001        01.07.2021           31.07.2021
001        01.08.2021           31.08.2021
001        01.09.2021           30.09.2021
001        01.10.2021           31.10.2021
002        01.02.2021           07.02.2021
002        08.02.2021           14.02.2021
002        15.02.2021           21.02.2021
002        22.02.2021           28.02.2021
002        01.03.2021           07.03.2021
002        08.03.2021           14.03.2021
002        15.03.2021           21.03.2021
002        22.03.2021           28.03.2021
002        29.03.2021           04.04.2021
002        05.04.2021           11.04.2021
002        12.04.2021           18.04.2021
002        19.04.2021           25.04.2021
002        26.04.2021           02.05.2021
002        03.05.2021           09.05.2021
002        10.05.2021           16.05.2021
002        17.05.2021           23.05.2021
002        24.05.2021           30.05.2021
002        31.05.2021           06.06.2021
002        07.06.2021           13.06.2021
002        14.06.2021           20.06.2021
002        21.06.2021           27.06.2021
002        28.06.2021           04.07.2021
002        05.07.2021           11.07.2021
002        12.07.2021           18.07.2021
002        19.07.2021           25.07.2021
002        26.07.2021           01.08.2021
002        02.08.2021           08.08.2021
002        09.08.2021           15.08.2021
002        16.08.2021           22.08.2021
002        23.08.2021           29.08.2021
002        30.08.2021           05.09.2021
002        06.09.2021           12.09.2021
002        13.09.2021           19.09.2021
002        20.09.2021           26.09.2021
002        27.09.2021           03.10.2021
002        04.10.2021           10.10.2021
002        11.10.2021           17.10.2021
002        18.10.2021           24.10.2021
002        25.10.2021           31.10.2021
003        01.02.2021           14.02.2021
003        15.02.2021           28.02.2021
003        01.03.2021           14.03.2021
003        15.03.2021           28.03.2021
003        29.03.2021           11.04.2021
003        12.04.2021           25.04.2021
003        26.04.2021           09.05.2021
003        10.05.2021           23.05.2021
003        24.05.2021           06.06.2021
003        07.06.2021           20.06.2021
003        21.06.2021           04.07.2021
003        05.07.2021           18.07.2021
003        19.07.2021           01.08.2021
003        02.08.2021           15.08.2021
003        16.08.2021           29.08.2021
003        30.08.2021           12.09.2021
003        13.09.2021           26.09.2021
003        27.09.2021           10.10.2021
003        11.10.2021           24.10.2021
003        25.10.2021           07.11.2021

68 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If you'd actually want to set periods regarding `customer.billing_start_date`, then all references to `date_range.start_date` should be modified to `billing_start_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for Postgres.

There is a slight difference compared to your expected output: the `pay_period_start` is calculated to not start before `billing_start_date`:

```
select t.customer, 
       case 
          when g.nr = 1 then t.billing_start_date
          else g.dt::date 
       end as pay_period_start, 
       case t.frequency
          when 'Weekly' then (g.dt + interval '1 week' - interval '1 day')::date
          when 'Bi-Weekly' then  (g.dt + interval '2 week' - interval '1 day')::date
          else (g.dt + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date
       end as pay_period_end
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(date_trunc('month', t.billing_start_date), date '2021-10-31', 
                             case t.frequency
                                when 'Weekly' then interval '1 week' 
                                when 'Bi-Weekly' then interval '2 week'
                                else  interval '1 month'
                              end
                            ) with ordinality as g(dt,nr)
order by t.customer, pay_period_start
```

If you indeed want `pay_period_start` to start on `2021-02-01` regardless of the actual `billing_start_date` you need to change the start value for `generate_series()` and the CASE expression for `pay_period_start` can also be simplified

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use:

```sql
WITH date_range (range_start, range_end) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-02-01', DATE '2021-10-01' FROM DUAL
),
periods (customer, frequency, period_start, range_end) AS (
  SELECT t.customer,
         t.frequency,
         CASE t.frequency
         WHEN 'Monthly'
         THEN ADD_MONTHS(
                billing_start_date,
                GREATEST(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(range_start, billing_start_date)), 0)
              )
         WHEN 'Bi-Weekly'
         THEN billing_start_date + 14 * GREATEST(TRUNC((range_start - billing_start_date)/14), 0)
         WHEN 'Weekly'
         THEN billing_start_date + 7 * GREATEST(TRUNC((range_start - billing_start_date)/7), 0)
         END,
         d.range_end
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN date_range d
  WHERE  t.billing_start_date <= d.range_end
UNION ALL
  SELECT customer,
         frequency,
         CASE frequency
         WHEN 'Monthly'   THEN ADD_MONTHS(period_start, 1)
         WHEN 'Bi-Weekly' THEN period_start + 14
         WHEN 'Weekly'    THEN period_start + 7
         END,
         range_end
  FROM   periods
  WHERE  period_start < range_end
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY customer SET order_rn
SELECT customer,
       frequency,
       period_start,
       CASE frequency
       WHEN 'Monthly'   THEN ADD_MONTHS(period_start, 1)
       WHEN 'Bi-Weekly' THEN period_start + 14
       WHEN 'Weekly'    THEN period_start + 7
       END - 1 AS period_end
FROM   periods
WHERE  period_start <= range_end;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Customer , Frequency, billing_start_date) AS
SELECT '001', 'Monthly',   DATE '2021-02-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '002', 'Weekly',    DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '003', 'Bi-Weekly', DATE '2020-03-05' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMER | FREQUENCY | PERIOD_START | PERIOD_END |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 001 | Monthly | 2021-02-04 00:00:00 | 2021-03-03 00:00:00 |
> | 001 | Monthly | 2021-03-04 00:00:00 | 2021-04-03 00:00:00 |
> | 001 | Monthly | 2021-04-04 00:00:00 | 2021-05-03 00:00:00 |
> | 001 | Monthly | 2021-05-04 00:00:00 | 2021-06-03 00:00:00 |
> | 001 | Monthly | 2021-06-04 00:00:00 | 2021-07-03 00:00:00 |
> | 001 | Monthly | 2021-07-04 00:00:00 | 2021-08-03 00:00:00 |
> | 001 | Monthly | 2021-08-04 00:00:00 | 2021-09-03 00:00:00 |
> | 001 | Monthly | 2021-09-04 00:00:00 | 2021-10-03 00:00:00 |
> | 002 | Weekly | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-07 00:00:00 |
> | 002 | Weekly | 2021-03-08 00:00:00 | 2021-03-14 00:00:00 |
> | 002 | Weekly | 2021-03-15 00:00:00 | 2021-03-21 00:00:00 |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | 002 | Weekly | 2021-09-13 00:00:00 | 2021-09-19 00:00:00 |
> | 002 | Weekly | 2021-09-20 00:00:00 | 2021-09-26 00:00:00 |
> | 002 | Weekly | 2021-09-27 00:00:00 | 2021-10-03 00:00:00 |
> | 003 | Bi-Weekly | 2021-01-21 00:00:00 | 2021-02-03 00:00:00 |
> | 003 | Bi-Weekly | 2021-02-04 00:00:00 | 2021-02-17 00:00:00 |
> | 003 | Bi-Weekly | 2021-02-18 00:00:00 | 2021-03-03 00:00:00 |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | 003 | Bi-Weekly | 2021-09-02 00:00:00 | 2021-09-15 00:00:00 |
> | 003 | Bi-Weekly | 2021-09-16 00:00:00 | 2021-09-29 00:00:00 |
> | 003 | Bi-Weekly | 2021-09-30 00:00:00 | 2021-10-13 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=55a644017e2d96e760b0162520284dbd)*